Alice and Bob play a Multi-Qubit game
Well I am quite new to this so excuse me if the question is absurd
Alice and Bob each can "measure" variables A and B respectively: Alice can use $a_1$ and $a_2$ methods of measurement while Bob can use $b_1$ and $b_2$ methods; the observations belong to the set $\{0,1\}$
I am given a generalized state probability matrix which provides me with $P(o_A,o_B|a_o,b_j)$ where $o_A$ and $o_B$ are the observations from the set $\{0,1\}$; so essentially a $4\times 4$ matrix
I am required to solve for a global probability distribution: for $a_1b_1a_2b_2$, where each of them can attain value of either $0$ or $1$ and one has to find the probability associated with the number obtained; essentially, one has to find 16 unknown probabilities from the 16 probabilities given in the matrix
Now of course I have created a linear system of equations to solve for the general solutions along with the null space basis, but this is clearly in qubits domain and requires much more rigour!
In some cases, no global distribution exists, and that happens because "the choice of Bob's measurement affects the probability of $a_1$'s outcomes" as per the problem
Now I get the drift that showing dependence might help but I really do not have much mathematical experience with this
It would be great if I could get an intuitive explanation followed up by an algorithmic answer to this!
Thanks!

Can you please clarify your question? Is there any assumption on the player's ability to communicate? Do they share a quantum state? What do you mean by "clearly in qubits domain"?

Also: what exactly is the matrix you are given and the one you need to derive from it? In the description they seem to be more or less the same. Giving the equations you want to solve might be clearer!
